# How to refresh my datagrid in c# wpf after use stored procedure in tableadapter

Tags: c#, wpf, stored-procedures, datagrid, refresh

I have set up to use the stored procedure in dataset to insert a new row.
The insert code work, but I don't know how to refresh the datagrid for it to show the new data. I setup my datagrid to bind to table like this.

I use the built-in option of visual studio datagrid to make connection. So a lot of part of the code I don't understand.

XAML

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="studentViewSource" Source="{Binding Student, Source={StaticResource studentDataDataSet}}"/>
<DataGrid x:Name="studentDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
</DataGrid>
```

C#

```
StudentDatabase.StudentDataDataSet studentDataDataSet = ((StudentDatabase.StudentDataDataSet)(this.FindResource("studentDataDataSet")));

// Load data into the table Student. You can modify this code as needed.
StudentDatabase.StudentDataDataSetTableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter studentDataDataSetStudentTableAdapter = new StudentDatabase.StudentDataDataSetTableAdapters.StudentTableAdapter();
studentDataDataSetStudentTableAdapter.Fill(studentDataDataSet.Student);

System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource studentViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("studentViewSource")));
studentViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

All these code automatically added by Visual Studio if you use their "Data Source"

Comment: is that Student is a property having propertyChanged handler enabled?

Comment: that student in "{Binding Student, Source" is the name of the table

Comment: Are you binding the itemsSource from code behind??

Comment: they automatic added when you use their datasource

Answer (score 0):

I found the method to do those. Just use the fucntion fill of table adapter. Can found in cs file of the window.  and set the tableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true; So every time you fill with default or your own fill function. They will clear the old and fill in the new.
Example:

```
 //Function called when window was load.
 private void window_load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    studentDataDataSetStudentTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
 }

 // Button event called when button press
 private void RefreshDataGrid(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    studentDataDataSetStudentTableAdapter.Fill(studentDataDataSet.Student);
 }
```